# Visual Studio 2013 Crystal report 13.0.8 do not open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I am working on an application, which comes from several migrations. It started in Visual `Studio 2012 and is now in Visual 2013`.
`Crystal version 13.0.28` is installed on the server and the application runs fine.

The last code sources were lost, and some time later, they gave me an old backup that I have to add new functionalities.

I have `Visual Studio 2013, Framework 4.5` installed.
I have the production web.config and I have these references to Crystal Report

```
<sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
      </sectionGroup>
```

and

```
  <assemblies>
      <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
        <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
      </assemblies>
```

I installed in my local PC `Crystal version 13.0.28 for 32 and 64 bits.` The same version is installed in Produccion.

Running Production version in my local IIS, the application runs fine.

I also have installed `SAP Crystal Report 2013 Viewer SP8 Version 14.1.8`

When I try to compile the Solution, I have a Crystal error for missed reference.

And I installed `Crystal Report SP 31 for 32 bits`. and Sap Crystal Report 13.0.8 was updated to 13.0.31

[image: Package installed]

The problem I am having is that when I run the application, the reports show a message saying 'parameters are missing'. and empty page.

Also, when I open any report from Visual Studio, it opens from `Crystal Viewer` but shows it blank saying that the report `has not data` and does not even show the design.

[image: Crystal Viewer]

If I deploy this solution in IIS, it shows the same error.

It seems that it does not recover the parameters that are passed from the application.

I also tried to copy the production .`rpt` to my environment, but it doesn't work either.

An issue that puzzles me is that the reports have a .RPT extension. This extension is for Crystal Report 8.
For Crystal Report 13 and Visual Studio 2013, the extension is RDLC.
How is it possible for reports with an .RPT extension to work with Crystal Report 13?

What am I forgetting?

Do I need another version? Any Service Pack?

It is better to Install Crystal Report 8?

Thanks

Comment: You are getting error message "No Data Saved".  See https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-q-a/error-message-no-saved-data/qaq-p/661476

Comment: thanks, but I can not see the report to enter the values... I added more comments to the problem

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/dynamics/sl/troubleshoot-crystal-report-errors

Answer (score 0):

I installed another version of Crystal report, that brings another problem I will comment in another post.

Thanks